# Recovery Mode for a program

Tags: windows, batch-file, recovery

I'm making a new version (of my old Batch program), which is called Encriipt BETA 16.3, that allows you to *encript* your private folder. It has a register system integrated on the program and I'd like to add a Recovery Mode (so in case you forget your user/password you won't lose everything). I'd like to put a security question or something, but i'm not sure, because if, for an instance, a friend enters and the question is "Where were you born?" or "Which was your primary school?" he will easily answer it and access to all the files, passwords,... Any ideas?

PS: I'm referring to which kind of recovery "things" I could do, not referred to inputs.

Comment: Is your question about how to get user input, or how to design a recovery system that won't allow people who know you to gain access to your account? Because if it's the second one, people have been trying for decades to figure that out and nobody's done it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is roughly analogous to Microsoft's [Bitlocker](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c61f2a12-8ae6-4957-b031-97b4d762cf31), which also encrypts data with a password. Their solution to forgotten passwords is to generate a long recovery key which users need to store securely away from the encrypted machine.

As SomethingDark stated in a comment, a simple security question is a bad idea because it's easier for other people to guess the answer to than the password.

Comment: And also because batch is plain text, so people can just open the script and see where the password is stored.

Comment: But i convert them to .exe, if I didn't the program wouldn't make sense.